# Loki - Hot corner close window

Tags: release-loki, pantheon, window-manager

In Loki, How do I set a 'Hot Corner' for closing the current window?  I've solved this myself and wanted to post the answer so others will hopefully find this.  Also a better method is always welcome.

Answer (score 2):

1. Install xdotool:

   ```
   sudo apt install xdotool
   ```
2. In 'Hot Corners' under 'Custom command' insert the following command:

   ```
   xdotool keydown Alt F4 keyup Alt F4
   ```